# Select text on first line AND another text on third line by regexp

Tags: regular-expressions

Suppose I has 2 jsons:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "action": "Handler:GET_DICTIONARY",
    "locale": "en",
    "data": {"dictionary_type":"EXCHANGE_RATES_AS_DICTIONARY"}
}
```

and

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "action": "Handler:GET_DICTIONARY",
    "locale": "en",
    "data": {"dictionary_type":"MTS"}
}
```

I need to select only second json by regexp.
The unique text to identify second json are:
on first line:
`GET_DICTIONARY`

**AND** 
on third line:

`MTS`

What is a correct regexp for this?

I try this regexp but it not help:

```
"GET_DIRCTIONARY C-q C-j
MTS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following input for `re-search-forward` will do:

`GET_DICTIONARY\(.*` <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> `\)\{2\}.*MTS`

The parenthesis `\(` and `\)` define a group that is exactly two times repeated by `\{2\}`. The content of the group is a sequence of arbitrary many non-newline characters `.*` and a newline that is input with <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>.

After the last newline the group is followed by arbitrary many non-newline-characters `.*` and then by `MTS`.

Your main errors were

1. that you didn't admit for the non-newline characters and
2. that you did only admit one newline.

The basic elements for regexps are described in the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html).